# Jquery remove class from many, add class to one

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, addclass, removeclass

A common operation I find myself doing is the following:

```
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li class="current">Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ul>

var $allLi = $('li');

$allLi.click(function(){
    $allLi.removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
});
```

Is there a way to condense this, somehow by combining $allLi and $(this) and using toggleClass?

Thanks!

Comment: What you are doing is about as efficient as it can be using jQuery methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jonathan's solution should work just fine but I would like to propose a different solution.

Rather than unsetting all the elements and then selecting the current one, why not just keep track of the *current* element and only perform the operation on that?

```
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li class="current">Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var current = $("li.current");
        $("li").click(function () {
            current.removeClass("current");
            current = $(this);
            current.addClass("current");
        });
    }());
</script>
```

It's *"longer"* but also more efficient.

My solution aims to have all state in JavaScript rather than partly in the DOM. `toggleClass` circumvents this principle. It's not so much a matter of "hey looks this a really long and super complex way of doing something simple", there's an idea behind it. If your application state gets more complex than just one selected element you'll run into issues if you try and stuff that state into the DOM. The DOM is just a 'view', keep your state in the 'model' (the JS code).

Comment: Why wouldn't you simply add the class in the same line of the setter?

Comment: Please don't make trivial edits to my code. Yes I know `current = $(this).addClass("current");` works, but does it make the code more readable? no.

Comment: Then I suppose we'll just have to disagree on that :) but as it's my solution I'd like to keep it to my preference.

Comment: Ok by me ... just thought I was helping you out.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you could add it, and remove it from the siblings:

```
$("li").on("click", function(){
  $(this)
    .addClass("current")
    .siblings()
      .removeClass("current");
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/owivih/edit#javascript,html,live